# Каким образом можно вернуть placeholder? TypeError: event is undefined

Tags: javascript

Написал простенький скрипт для создания `placeholder'a` у `select` элементов. Выдает ошибку

> TypeError: event is undefined

Попробовал в слушателе событий обернуть функцию, которая реагирует на событие, обернуть в анонимную функцию и передать основной объект событий, не помогло, в чем проблема может быть?

И следующий вопрос, как можно вернуть `placeholder` на место, если пользователь ничего не выбрал, а просто убрал фокус с элемента? Интересует конкретно, как отловить тот момент, что пользователь ничего не выбрал?

```js
function SelectPlaceholder(options) {

  this.select = document.querySelectorAll(options.selectSelector);
  this.styleClass = options.placeholderStyleClass;

  self = this;

  this.deletePlaceholder = function(event) {
    var currentElement = event.target;
    var placeholderChild = currentElement.querySelector(options.placeholderSelector);

    if (placeholderChild) {
      currentElement.removeChild(placeholderChild);
    }

  }

  (function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.select.length; i++) {
      self.select[i].classList.add(self.styleClass);
    }
  }());

  for (var i = 0; i < this.select.length; i++) {
    this.select[i].addEventListener('focus', function() {
      self.deletePlaceholder(event)
    });
  }


}

new SelectPlaceholder({
  selectSelector: '.field-line__select',
  placeholderSelector: '.field-line__select-placeholder',
  placeholderStyleClass: 'selectplaceholder-field',
});
```

```html
<select class="field-line__select">
  <option value="" class="field-line__select-placeholder">Открыть список улиц</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Чем Вам не нравится стандартный способ: `<option value="" disabled selected>Открыть список улиц</option>` ? Проясните логику скрипта.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.select[i].addEventListener('focus', function(event) { // !!!
  self.deletePlaceholder(event)
});

//(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < self.select.length; i++) {
    self.select[i].classList.add(self.styleClass);
  }
//}());
```

> пользователь ... убрал фокус с элемента

```
addEventListener.('blur', ...
```

Comment: Добавил, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно при наведение на что у Вас должен срабатывать placeholder. Как я понял при наведение на select. Как вариант:

```
 let select = document.getElementsByClassName('field-line__select');
    select[0].addEventListener('mouseenter', function (e) { 
      //тут работаем с элементом.
      console.log(e.target)
    })
```